# Nikon D5100 / D5200: which should I buy

Tags: nikon, dslr, nikon-d5100

I am currently looking into buying my first DSLR

After consideration I was pretty much set to buy a Nikon D5100, but looking at amazon it seems that there is only a $100 difference with the 5200.
If I consider the body  + lens kit ($600/700) + one lens ($200), it brings the total cost from $800 to $900, so a 11% increase

Is the higher resolution sensor, newer software and more precise auto-focus worth the $100 price difference ?

Comment: Both of these cameras will let you take great pictures and the limiting factor is probably you as a photographer until you get very good. You have to be much more specific with your requirements and needs if you expect us to be able to tell if the extra $100 for the D5200 is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a personal choice based on how much you value the features.

Go over the specifications, read the reviews, then decided.

No one here can make that decision for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the newer product is the better product. The **Nikon D5200** has many improved features over the D5100. Some of them are ISO sensitivity, higher FPS, more AF points (39 vs 11). So your extra bucks will definitely pay off.

Comment: How do you know that th $100 extra will definitely pay itself off? We don't know anything about Olotiar's needs. Although one can argue that extra or improved features of a camera is a good thing it has to be put in relationship with the additional cost. There are a lot of cameras that has far higher specs than the D5200 at a far higher price and vice versa - all of them valid purchases, but not one over them other until we know about the need of the buyer.

Comment: I have added those advantages which will be paid off for his money.

Comment: Still how do you expect those features to "pay themselves off"? As far as we know Olotiar is not a professional photographer, especially since this will be his/her first DSLR, so there is no no money earn from these extra features. Unless there are money generated from jobs the only thing that matters us how much he/she values the features compared to the extra cost they bring with them.